# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString does not work ios8

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, webview

I am using the following code to focus data on my textfield, on previous ios it worked well but in ios8  it's not working. Can anybody help me:

```
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var textField = document.activeElement;"
                        "textField.value = '%@';"
                        "document.activeElement.form.submit();", rawBytes];
[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this? Have you looked at the console log?

Comment: what does rawBytes contains?

Comment: rawBytes here is a string. Ive printed the String and its not nil.